# Extrend QAbstractListModel to display custom background color?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Greetings all,

[image: http://oi51.tinypic.com/6hrm9w.jpg]

I have extended my own QAbstractListModel to change the background color of QCombobox.
As seen it the image  ,I have two issues.
1) As shown in the first image snapshot , background color doesnt appear for the selected item.
2) When selecting items , the background turns in to default highlight color (light blue)

Is there anyway to fix these two issues ?

Here is my QAbstractListModel implementation.

```
RzContourLabelModel::RzContourLabelModel(RzContourLabelContext *contourLabelCtx,int max,QObject *parent) : QAbstractListModel(parent){


    contourCtx=contourLabelCtx;
    QList contourLabels=contourLabelCtx->getLabels();

    for(int i=0;i= colorLabels.size())
                return QVariant();

         if (role == Qt::DisplayRole){
             QString str;
             str.setNum(colorLabels.at(index.row()));
             return str;
         }

         if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
         {
             int labelNum=colorLabels.at(index.row());
             QColor col= contourCtx->getLabelColor(labelNum);
             return col;
         }
               return QVariant();
 }
```

Comment: How do you want to visualize selection if not by color? Maybe try with setSelectionMode( NoSelection ) to disable selection. Not sure if QComboBox can handle that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both features (background of the selected item and highlighting color) are controlled by the view. Here is a quote from the docs:

> For the text and icon in the combobox label, the data in the model that has the `Qt::DisplayRole` and `Qt::DecorationRole` is used.

So the background of  the selected item wont be easy to change. Instead you might want to make color icons and return them as the `Qt::DecorationRole` in the model.

For the highlighting color - you can reimplement this with a custom item delegate. See `QComboBox::setItemDelegate`

Answer (score 2):

You may try to play with Qt CSS...

Not sure this help you but it may:

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    selection-background-color: Transparent;
    selection-color: Black;
}
```

it prevents from colorizing selection, the only thing i am not sure about - will it paint your widget's background or your item's background in case of selection. If it will paint widget's background - it is useless :(